# How to print string value one by one using javascript for loop?

Tags: javascript

> This is my string "HelloHowAre" I want to print it like this -  Hello How Are Using For loop

Comment: is this static string ???

Comment: Help me please how i can print it one bye one using for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with the below javascript code

```
var newvalll = 'HelloHowAre'.match(/[A-Z][a-z]+|[0-9]+/g);
   var res = String(newvalll);
   var nameArr = res.split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < nameArr.length; i++) {
     alert(nameArr[i]);
}
```

I think this is help to you

Comment: thank you so much its working fine